# IDE for Grinder scripting

Tags: ide, grinder

I'm looking for a IDE for the Grinder framework 3.11. 
Can someone please suggest me an IDE to develop and run Grinder(3.11) scripts. 
Grinder-stone for eclipse is no longer supported.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there are no good IDE options today for doing fully-integrated Grinder script development.  Nothing has come along to fill Grinderstone's shoes.  Your best bet is to go with a decent Java/Python/Jython development tool such as PyDev or PyCharm or IntelliJ.  It won't have the Grinder integration, but any of these tools will be helpful for everything else.

Answer (score 1):

I was in your shoes few days back however you need to configure pydev which will save a lot of time . You can integrated Grinder on your own by creating a bat file and giving the path of scripts to the one in eclipse . This worked for me.